# can't figure out SimpleXML syntax

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to parse some items from a log of soap request XML and can't seem to figure out how to get to the innards of a SimpleXMLElement. Here's an example of the XML I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9">
     <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:RateRequest>
       <ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <ns1:UserCredential>
         <ns1:Key>aaaaaaaaaaa</ns1:Key>
         <ns1:Password>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</ns1:Password>
        </ns1:UserCredential>
       </ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
       <ns1:ClientDetail>
        <ns1:AccountNumber>11111111</ns1:AccountNumber>
        <ns1:MeterNumber>88888888</ns1:MeterNumber>
       </ns1:ClientDetail>
       <ns1:TransactionDetail>
        <ns1:CustomerTransactionId>1</ns1:CustomerTransactionId>
       </ns1:TransactionDetail>
       <ns1:Version>
        <ns1:ServiceId>crs</ns1:ServiceId>
        <ns1:Major>9</ns1:Major>
        <ns1:Intermediate>0</ns1:Intermediate>
        <ns1:Minor>0</ns1:Minor>
       </ns1:Version>
       <ns1:ReturnTransitAndCommit>true</ns1:ReturnTransitAndCommit>
       <ns1:RequestedShipment>
        <ns1:ShipTimestamp>2013-08-06T12:39:26-04:00</ns1:ShipTimestamp>
        <ns1:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns1:DropoffType>
        <ns1:Shipper>
         <ns1:AccountNumber>11111111</ns1:AccountNumber>
         <ns1:Address>
          <ns1:StreetLines>24 Seaview Blvd</ns1:StreetLines>
          <ns1:City>Port Washington</ns1:City>
          <ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>NY</ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>
          <ns1:PostalCode>11050</ns1:PostalCode>
          <ns1:CountryCode>US</ns1:CountryCode>
         </ns1:Address>
        </ns1:Shipper>
        <ns1:Recipient>
         <ns1:Address>
          <ns1:StreetLines>1234 Fifth Street</ns1:StreetLines>
          <ns1:City>Sixton</ns1:City>
          <ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>AR</ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>
          <ns1:PostalCode>72712</ns1:PostalCode>
          <ns1:CountryCode>US</ns1:CountryCode>
         </ns1:Address>
        </ns1:Recipient>
        <ns1:ShippingChargesPayment>
         <ns1:Payor>
          <ns1:AccountNumber>11111111</ns1:AccountNumber>
          <ns1:CountryCode>US</ns1:CountryCode>
         </ns1:Payor>
        </ns1:ShippingChargesPayment>
        <ns1:RateRequestTypes>ACCOUNT</ns1:RateRequestTypes>
        <ns1:PackageCount>1</ns1:PackageCount>
        <ns1:PackageDetail>INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES</ns1:PackageDetail>
        <ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>
         <ns1:Weight>
          <ns1:Units>LB</ns1:Units>
          <ns1:Value>14</ns1:Value>
         </ns1:Weight>
         <ns1:Dimensions>
          <ns1:Length>20</ns1:Length>
          <ns1:Width>20</ns1:Width>
          <ns1:Height>9</ns1:Height>
          <ns1:Units>IN</ns1:Units>
         </ns1:Dimensions>
        </ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>
       </ns1:RequestedShipment>
      </ns1:RateRequest>
     </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to get out values like the CountryCode, PostalCode Weight->Value and all of the Dimensions but the namespaces are confusing me. Any time I parse it, and look in the debugger all I see for any given variable is {SimpleXMLElement} [0] yet some will show output with ->asXML() but most of my attempts to access data either error out, return false, or return another {SimpleXMLElement} [0]. I just want the string/value for these nodes!

The following for example, outputs absolutely nothing:

```
    $fReq = simplexml_load_string($xmlRequest);
    $fReq->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9');
    $ns = $fReq->getNameSpaces(true);
    $rr = $fReq->children($ns['ns1']);
    echo $rr->asXML()."\n";
```

Comment: Don't use `print_r` or `var_dump` to inspect SimpleXML objects, they will mislead you completely. Try the functions here: https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using XMLReader: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php

This is a example form PHP with small modification for match your requirements:

```
function xmlParse($content,$wrapperName,$callback,$limit=NULL){
    $xml = new XMLReader();
    $xml->xml($content);

    $n=0;
    $x=0;
    while($xml->read()){
        if($xml->nodeType==XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == $wrapperName){
            while($xml->read() && $xml->name != $wrapperName){
                if($xml->nodeType==XMLReader::ELEMENT){
                    $name = $xml->name;
                    $xml->read();
                    $value = $xml->value;
                    if(preg_match("/[^\s]/",$value)){
                        $subarray[$name] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }
            if($limit==NULL || $x<$limit){
                if($callback($subarray)){
                    $x++;
                }
                unset($subarray);
            }
            $n++;
        }
    }
    $xml->close();
}

xmlParse($test,'SOAP-ENV:Envelope','callback');

function callback($array){
    var_dump($array);

}
```

Just execute this with you XML and will return

```
Array
(
    [ns1:Key] => aaaaaaaaaaa
    [ns1:Password] => aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    [ns1:AccountNumber] => 11111111
    [ns1:MeterNumber] => 88888888
    [ns1:CustomerTransactionId] => 1
    [ns1:ServiceId] => crs
    [ns1:Major] => 9
    [ns1:Intermediate] => 0
    [ns1:Minor] => 0
    [ns1:ReturnTransitAndCommit] => true
    [ns1:ShipTimestamp] => 2013-08-06T12:39:26-04:00
    [ns1:DropoffType] => REGULAR_PICKUP
    [ns1:StreetLines] => 1234 Fifth Street
    [ns1:City] => Sixton
    [ns1:StateOrProvinceCode] => AR
    [ns1:PostalCode] => 72712
    [ns1:CountryCode] => US
    [ns1:RateRequestTypes] => ACCOUNT
    [ns1:PackageCount] => 1
    [ns1:PackageDetail] => INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES
    [ns1:Units] => IN
    [ns1:Value] => 14
    [ns1:Length] => 20
    [ns1:Width] => 20
    [ns1:Height] => 9
)
```

Regards

Comment: Well, thanks for the response, but I'm not really looking to learn a whole new syntax of a whole new command. I tried a few things with xmlreader and while it lets me get to some properties easily with the example xml I gave, I'm also having to parse the responses which came back from fedex which include some repeating elements and I don't really feel like trying to figure out yet another xml parser to get at them.
The question was about SimpleXMLElement - anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `registerXPathNamespace` unless you're using XPath. You do, however, need to traverse through the SOAP `Body` element, which means you need to think about two namespaces, not just one.

It's also a good idea not to rely on namespace prefixes like `ns1` staying the same in the future; the part that's guaranteed is the actual URI in the `xmlns` attribute. One way to make this more readable is to define constants for the XML namespaces used in your application, and pass those to the `->children()` and `->attributes()` methods when necessary.

Note also that `->children()` "selects" a namespace until further notice, so once you've selected the Fedex namespace and traversed to the `RateRequest` node, you can just access elements as though namespaces weren't an issue (since everything below that in this document is in that same namespace).

Here's a completed example showing how this might look ([see a live demo here](http://codepad.org/4LsEDK8s)).

```
// Give your own aliases to namespaces, don't rely on the XML always having the same ones
define('NS_SOAP', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
define('NS_FEDEX_RATE', 'http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9');

// Parse the XML
$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
// $sx now represents the <SOAP-ENV:Envelope> element

// Traverse through the SOAP Body
$sx_soap_body = $sx->children(NS_SOAP)->Body;

// Now "switch" to the Fedex namespace, and start with the RateRequest node
$sx_rate_request = $sx_soap_body->children(NS_FEDEX_RATE)->RateRequest;

// Now traverse as normal, e.g. to the Recipient's CountryCode
// (the string cast isn't necessary for echo, but is a good habit to get into)
echo (string)$sx_rate_request->RequestedShipment->Recipient->Address->CountryCode;
```